# how to add number of days into a given date in the format mm/dd/yyyy?

Tags: java, date

How to add number of days into a given date in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` .

If my date is `9/12/2007`, I want to add 30 days into the date and the result should be `10/12/2007`.

I have many frequencies like **Weekly, monthly, Every 2 weeks, Twice a month, Every 4 weeks, Once in 2 months, Every 3 months, Every 6 months, Every 3 months,
Annually,** etc.

If we  select the different frequencies from the list, the result should vary based on the frequency. Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Are you using Java 8 or earlier Java version?

Comment: It is unclear why you can not do this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String dt = "9/12/2007";  // Start date
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(sdf.parse(dt));
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert your date to a `LocalDate`, add the required values to it and then convert it back to the format you need it.

For example adding 30 days would look like this:

```
LocalDate d = LocalDate.of(2007,9,12).plus(30, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
```

And if you look at  `ChronoUnit` you can see there are some units defined like weeks, days, months and so on...